# Adding a Maven repository to settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, m2e

I am trying to add a repository to my settings.xml file so I can use the libraries in that repository in a project I am working on.  here is my current settings.xml file.

```
<settings>
  .
  .

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      ...
      <repositories>

      <repository>
          <id>xuggle repo</id>
          <name>Xuggler Repository</name>
          <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
      ...
      </pluginRepositories>

    </profile>
  </profiles>
  .
</settings>
```

I want to add the Xuggler repository to my settings.xml so I can search for the proper dependencies in M2E (Maven 2 Eclipse) and add them to my project.  When I I go to windo->show view->Maven->maven repositories the xuggle repository is visible but completely empty.  The Jars I need aren't being found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to support [search](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#How_Search_Works) and browsing of remote repositories from m2e, repository has to provide m2e indexes. Here are [somewhat outdated docs](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Nexus+Indexer).

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is to use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus to manage the repositories you need.

See here how to configure the settings file: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-maven.html#ex-maven-nexus-simple